# Как взять значение из одной переменной в другую, но не делать ссылку на неё?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ссылки

У меня есть список, значение которого берёт другой список:

```
objects = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
objects2 = objects
```

и я хочу чтобы второй не ссылался на первый

```
print(objects, objects2)
# вывод: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

#изменение
objects2.remove(3)
print(objects, objects2)
# вывод:[1, 2, 4, 5] [1, 2, 4, 5]

#ид
print(id(objects), id(objects2))
# вывод: 1416642614272 1416642614272
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `.copy()`

```
objects2 = objects.copy()
```

Если объект вложенный/составной и нужна глубокая копия, то [deepcopy](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-copy.html)

Answer (score 3):

Только для списка без вложений `objects2 = objects[:]` Ну а для других объектов, естественно, `copy/deepcopy`.

Answer (score 1):

Для получения "мелкой" копии (достаточной в вашем случае) есть три равноценных способа:

1. `objects2 = objects.copy()`
2. `objects2 = list(objects)`
3. `objects2 = objects[:]`

Однако, лучше всего использовать `.copy()`, как наиболее понятный способ - мы делаем копию, и это видно по названию используемого метода. "Явное лучше не явного".

Для получения "глубокой" копии (когда в списке не значения, а объекты) нужно использовать метод `copy.deepcopy`:

```
from copy import deepcopy

objects2 = deepcopy(objects)
```